# setTimeout in javascript make function run faster

Tags: javascript, date, settimeout

I have an application which I have to push a lot values to array, so I test the execution time:

```
var st = new Date().getTime();
var a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20971520; i++) {
  a.push(i);
}
var ed = new Date().getTime();
console.info((ed - st) / 1000);
console.info(a.length);
```

I run the codes in Firefox Console and Chrome console directly, and it cost `37 seconds`. And during the execution, even the mouse can be moved in Chrome, but there is no interactive effect.

Then I change the codes:

```
function push() {
  var st = new Date().getTime();
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 20971520; i++) {
    a.push(i);
  }
  var ed = new Date().getTime();
  console.info((ed - st) / 1000);
  console.info(a.length);
}

var tr = setTimeout(push, 50);
```

Simplify put the codes in a function, and call it using the `setTimeout`, it cost `0.844 second`. And during the execution, I can operation in Chrome normally.

[image: Screenshot of console]

What's going on here?

I know that the `setTimeout` will put the control to the browser to do the UI job, which will make the page responsive. For example, when I do some calculation during the mousemove of the page, I would put the calculation executed delayed to prevent it blocking the UI.

But why it reduce the total execution time of the same codes?

Comment: Maybe it's just caching. Have you tried to swap the execution order, i.e. first run the setTimeout variant and then the other one?

Comment: What happens if you just call `push()` ?

Comment: It takes the same time with or without the timeout for me.

Comment: Running code in the console should not be seen as a reasonnable way to test execution speed. Code in a function is optimized by the engine.

Comment: @dystroy: It seems that you are right, since I found that execute `push()` directly will cost the same time as that of using the `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Freez:See my comment to dystroy.

Comment: I am unable to delete my answer which is incorrect. Both variations of your code should run with almost similar speed inside webpages. The 10x difference is because of the way Chrome dev tools evaluate expressions, most probably because it uses a [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Performance_pro_.26_contra) block which initially searches for `a`, `i` etc in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5):

> And during the execution, I can operation in Chrome normally.

Not true. The main chrome window will be just as frozen as the other case (just for a shorter while). The debug tools are a separate thread and will not slow down though.

> But why it reduce the total execution time of the same codes?

It does if you run in dev tools. If you execute the code in actuality where the VM can make property optimizations the times are comparable (nearly 1 second). e.g.

```
   var st = new Date().getTime();
   var a = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 20971520; i++) {
       a.push(i);
   }
   var ed = new Date().getTime();
   console.info('normal', (ed - st) / 1000);
   console.info(a.length);

   function push() {
       var st = new Date().getTime();
       var a = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < 20971520; i++) {
           a.push(i);
       }
       var ed = new Date().getTime();
       console.info('timeout', (ed - st) / 1000);
       console.info(a.length);
   }

   var tr = setTimeout(push, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gu9Lg52j/ you will see the `normal` executes *just as fast* as `setTimeout`.

Also if you wrap the code in a function and execute in a console the time will be comparable even without a `setTimeout` as the VM can make optimizations between function definition and execution:

```
  function push() {
       var st = new Date().getTime();
       var a = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < 20971520; i++) {
           a.push(i);
       }
       var ed = new Date().getTime();
       console.info('timeout', (ed - st) / 1000);
       console.info(a.length);
   }
   push();
```

Comment: Your fiddle uses `onload` which changed the way code is executed.

Comment: @SalmanA you were right. I changed the fiddle to execute raw and the results are still comparable.

Answer (score 2):

Both variations of code should run with almost identical speed (the latter example might be faster but not 10 times faster).

Inside the Chrome developer tools, there is a different story. The expressions are evaluated inside a [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) block. This means the variables such as `a` and `i` are first searched inside another object (the [`__commandLineAPI`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api)). This adds an additional overhead which results in the 10 times longer execution time.

Comment: That's not really the reason. The function (your IIFE) is the reason.

Comment: The point is that in this example you are pushing inside a local variable `a` instead of `window.a`.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't impact the performance so much as putting the code in a function (try with `window.a`)

Comment: Try moving all variables outside the function, that makes the IIFE take 36 seconds, same as the naked code.

Comment: @dystroy you just forgot window.i

Answer (score 1):

All JavaScript engines perform various optimizations. For example V8 uses 2 compilers, a simple one used by default and an optimizing one. Code not compiled by the optimizing compiler is *slow*, very slow.

A condition for the optimizing compiler to run is that the code must be in a (not too long) function ([there are other conditions](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)). The first code you tried in the console isn't in a function. Put your first code in a function and you'll see it performs the same than the second one, `setTimeout` changes nothing.

It makes zero sense to check for performances in the console when the main performance factor is the optimizing compilation. If you're targeting node, use a benchmarking framework. If you're targeting the browser, use a site like [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/).

Now, when you have to do a really long computation in the browser (which doesn't seem to be the case here), you should consider [using web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage) which do the job in a background thread not impacting the UI.

Comment: How about if I have to run long calculation in Nodewebkit, in fact, I just wonder if creating an array with millions of elements will block the UI? That's why I test the function.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout`, like others noticed, doesn't speed up the array creation and *does* lock the browser. If you are concerned about browser lockup during the array creation, *web workers* (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage)) may come to the rescue. Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/p3ts3Lkg/) demo using a web worker for your code. The worker code is within the html:

```
onmessage = function (e) {
   var a = [], now = new Date;
   for (var i=0; i<20971520; i++) {
     a.push(i);
   }
   postMessage({timings: 'duration: '+(new Date()-now) + 
                         'Ms, result: [' + a[0] + '...'+a[a.length-1] + ']'});
 }
```